# Nlog - unable to log aspnet-request-ip

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I've .net core application and I want to log user IP address who request for the api/performing action.
I used ${aspnet-request-ip} it doesn't log IP of client.
How to log IP?

Here is my nlog.config:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          autoReload="true"
          internalLogLevel="Info"
          internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

        <extensions>
            <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
            <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.Logging"/>
            <add assembly="NLog"/>
        </extensions>
    
        <variable name="ExceptionLayout" value="${longdate} [${processid}] ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger} ${environment-user} ${aspnet-request-ip} ${aspnet-request-url} ${aspnet-request-method} ${message}${exception:format=tostring,Stacktrace}"/>
        <variable name="CommonLayout" value="${longdate} [${processid}] ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger} ${environment-user} ${aspnet-request-ip} ${message} "/>
        <variable name ="logDir" value="${aspnet-appbasepath}\logs" />
    
        <targets async="true">
            <!-- write logs to file  -->
            <target xsi:type="File" name="file"  layout="${CommonLayout}" fileName="${logDir}\log-${shortdate}.log" />
            <target name="fileAsException"
                    xsi:type="FilteringWrapper"
                    condition="length('${exception}')>0">
                <target xsi:type="File"
                        fileName="${logDir}\log-${shortdate}.log"
                        layout="${ExceptionLayout}" />
            </target>
        </targets>

        <rules>
            <logger name="*" writeTo="file,fileAsException">
                    <when condition="equals('${logger}','Elastic.Apm')" action="Ignore" />
            </logger>
            <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
        </rules>
    </nlog>
```

here is startup.cs

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
                var authClient = new FusionAuthClient(apiKey: Configuration.GetSection("fusionAuth:apiKey").Value, host: Configuration.GetSection("fusionAuth:url").Value);
                services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("finance", policy =>
                    {
                        policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenRequirement());
    
                    });
                });
                services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
                services.AddSingleton<ILogger, Logger>();
            }
```

here is log sample

```
2020-10-15 10:33:25.2828 [85588] DEBUG FinanceAPI.Program bhavin  Application started 
2020-10-15 10:33:27.4457 [85588] WARN HttpsRedirectionMiddleware bhavin  Failed to determine the https port for redirect. 
2020-10-15 10:33:27.9773 [85588] ERROR DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware bhavin  http://bhavin/favicon.ico GET An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
```

Comment: Can you show us your `authentication `configuration in `startup`?

Comment: I don't,because it's authorization poilicy. fusionauth auth used

Comment: `AddAuthentication` in your `startup`

Comment: fusionauth authenticate already

Comment: Replaced this `${aspnet-Request-Ip}` and it works

Comment: Instead of `services.AddSingleton<ILogger, Logger>();` then it should be `services.AddLogging(logging => { logging.ClearProviders(); logging.AddNLog(); });`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

Comment: i already added this in program.cs